# Error Response: has too many files (greater than 1000). gcloud app deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pip, plaid

We are deploying an application in Google App Engine. Ours is a standard engine on python 3.7.

Here is the requirements.txt file

```
 apiclient
 firebase_admin
 google.auth
 jinja2
 pytz
 stripe
 flask
 gunicorn
 requests
 requests_toolbelt
 google-cloud-tasks
 plaid-python
```

We are getting the following error when we deploy the application. There are only a total of 7654 files in total inside the lib folder.

```
  ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] The directory [lib/plaid/model] has too many files (greater than 1000).
```

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory, so what is your question?

Comment: According to documentation there is a limit of 10,000 files. We  have only 7,654 files in total. Why is this error. How do we solve it?

Comment: the lib/plaid/model is 2,352 files. According to the error this number cannot be greater than 1000? Is this true? Don't see this in Google documentation. If it is true, how do we solve this?

Comment: If you are running Python 3.X (is it 3.6 or 3.7? Your answers varies...), then dont bundle the libraries among the files you are trying to upload, but use `requirements.txt` as @NoCommandLine mentioned and let AppEngine install the dependencies in the instance for you instead.

Comment: We ended up using @NoCommandLine's suggestion, let the AppEngine install the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the number of files for an App is 10,000 (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/quotas#Files)) but maybe there's a limit of 1000 per folder

For GAE Standard, Python 2.7 doesn't use the `requirements.txt` file. This means you would have installed all the contents of that file in your `lib` folder and that folder gets uploaded (deployed) to Google. The number of files in that folder has passed 1000 (that's the error you're getting).

You should switch to Python 3. For Python 3, Google uses your `requirements.txt` file. Add your virtual environment folder to the `.gclooudignore` file so that when you deploy, your virtual env folder won't get deployed. During deploy, Google will install the contents of your `requirements.txt` file directly in cloud

Another reason you should switch to Python 3 is that Google has moved all new development to Python 3 ( I think they'll officially stop supporting Python 2 sometime next year; not 100% sure of this though)

Comment: Sorry. We use Python 3.6 not 2.7 (as mentioned earlier). Can you confirm if there is a limit of 1000 files in one folder? How do we overcome this since we are just importing the plain-python library.

Comment: @Jacktileman: If you're using ```Python 3.x```, then you shouldn't have a ```lib``` folder unless that's where you activated a virtual env. In that case, you should have a ```.gcloudignore``` file in the root of your application folder and you should include the ```lib``` folder in it. The deploy command ignores all files/folders listed in the ```.gcloudignore```. If you do this, the error you're seeing will go away

Comment: We currently don't do any local testing. We use Python 3.7. In our case can we remove the lib folder completely and just upload our app, along with requirements.txt? Will this install all the 3rd party libraries in GCP? Can we do this without activating the virtual environment in our local machine?

Comment: @Jacktileman: Yes. See my answer for an explanation on how Python 3.x works. Also see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#dependencies)